# Linked list representation of a polynomial

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to write a program to sum two polynomials. For the purpose, first of all, I am writing a program to take two polynomials and print them.

My program is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int power;
    int coef;
    struct node *link;
};



int input( struct node *Phead);
int display( struct node *Phead);

int main()
{
    struct node *Phead= malloc(sizeof(struct node)),*Qhead = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    input(Phead);
    display(Phead);

    input(Qhead);
    display(Qhead);

    return 0;
}

int input( struct node *Phead)
{
    //Phead 
    //Qhead = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int value;

    printf("\n\t\tEntry of polynomial:\n");

    printf("Enter the coefficient: ");
    scanf("%d",&Phead->coef);
    printf("Enter the power: ");
    scanf("%d",&Phead->power);
    Phead->link = NULL ;

    printf("Enter the coefficient,( 0 to break ): ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    while ( value != 0 )
    {
        struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node ));

        new_node -> coef = value;

        printf("Enter the power: ");
        scanf("%d",&new_node->power);
        new_node->link = Phead;
        Phead = new_node; 
        //printf("%d",Phead->power);
        printf("Enter the coefficient,( 0 to break ): ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }
    return 0;
}

int display( struct node *Phead)
{
    struct node *temp = Phead;
    //printf("I am in display.\n");

    while ( temp != NULL )
    {
        //printf("I am in while.\n");
        printf("%d * x ^ %d + ",temp->coef,temp->power);
        temp=temp->link;
    }
    //printf("%d * x ^ %d + ",temp->coef,temp->power);
    //printf("0");

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to print the polynomial.The issue is with temp variable. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting a debugging slave.

Comment: "I am unable to print the polynomial." - Ok, so what happens when you *try* to print the polynomial ?? "My code doesn't do what I want" isn't a question; it's a *problem*. That said, try making sure your tail-node is terminated with a NULL `next` member.

Comment: @MartinJames I debugged the question and then asked. I am a beginner, and do not know to ask good questions. Please help me.

Comment: A good question of this type would describe *what you expected to happen*, and then *what happened instead*, in great detail.  You appear to know that there is a problem with `temp`, but *what is that problem*?  What did you observe to happen that was different from what you expected?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is with your this part of code:

```
new_node->link = Phead;
Phead = new_node;
```

Solve it as follows:

```
Phead->link = new_node;
Phead = new_node;
```

Comment: This is completely backwards. The list is not build forward; it is built like a stack. The proposed solution orphans any content referenced by `Phead` with each new node insertion, leaking memory for bonus points.